# I installed Kali linux and configured Grub2 using EasyBcd. When I try to boot into Kali at the start I get an error 0xc000007

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I installed Kali Linux in Windows 10, dual booting. In this case, Windows 10 will be open at the same time it's perfectly working. But Kali Linux doesn't open because it shows the following error:

> Windows Boot Manager error windows failed to start
>
> File: \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr
>
> Status : 0xc000007
>
> info : The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.

I am using EASY BCD software.

[image]

Comment: If you don't know how to properly setup dual booting or find the solution to this using Google, the chances are that Kali isn't for you. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626/169376

Comment: Kali linux is just incidental here. The real problem is trying to use Windows Boot Manger to boot Linux.

Comment: Considering that you already have Windows working I'm betting you already have an ESP partition. So unless you went out of your way to make grub not install it should already be installed.

Answer (score 1):

First go into your UEFI firmware either using a key at boot usually F10 for boot menu or in Windows run `shutdown /r /fw /t 5` which will restart your computer into your UEFI firmware. From there find the boot menu. There should be an entry for grub or Kali. If not its because you installed Kali in legacy mode. If thats the case you should reinstall with GPT and an ESP partition of 256MiB then the rest of your partitions that you want like root /, /home and swap. When grub is installed it will detect legacy mode, BIOS partition or ESP partition accordingly. As long as you create the ESP partition the install should get Grub working for you and in general don't count on Windows Boot Manger to boot anything but Windows.